# How to insert customer and order info at same time with matching keys

Tags: sql, visual-studio, foreign-keys, primary-key, tableadapter

[MyForm1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q66hl.jpg)

[MYCode(withError)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLIBT.jpg)

[MYForm2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkBhJ.jpg)

Lets say I have two tables for simplicity (the real database has more tables like the pictures imply); both primary keys are auto-increment do not allow nulls, the foreign key allows nulls. I need to understand a fundamental concept:

One table is called customers, with the following columns:

- customer_id (pk)
- name
- phone

The second table is called orders:

- order_id (pk)
- customer_id (fk)
- product
- quantity

There is an Order form for a new customer, where you have to enter the customer info (name, phone) and the order info (product, quantity). I made text boxes for these on the form and a button.

How do I insert this info into the correct tables while ensuring the keys match after its done? I want the form to add customer info and tie orders to them.

I have tried table adapters, watched Youtube, written SQL queries and even typing in the data manually in the server explorer. I can retrieve data easily but inserting confuses me because of keys and auto increment. I think I am missing a fundamental concept. It seems that tutorials almost never show inserting data into multiple tables? Do I need a trigger or scope identity in my table adapter query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataset represents your database tables; you fill the dataset's tables with data, and then call update in the right order (you have to insert things into order and products before you can insert into orderitems)

If you're doing this in a modern version of VS your dataset will also generate a TableAdapterManager, a device that knows of all the tableadapters in the set and the order they should be used in to achieve correct functionality so doing the inserts is as simple as calling `tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll()`, tableAdapterManager being an instance of the TableAdapterManager class

There is a huge amount of info needed to pass to you to really answer your question, and I can't see the code so I can't tell how you've arranged things thus far, but in essence you either need your Orders and Products tables to already have data in them (downloaded from the db) or they need to have rows inserted as part of the order creation. Logically, I would assume the products are known. I also don't know if you're using VB or C# - i'll write in VB, as a C# programmer is probably less likely to complain about having to mentally translate the VB than vice versa:

```vb
   Dim prodToAdd = ds.Products.Find(1234) 'gets a row from the product table with id 1234

   'create an order
   Dim order = ds.Orders.NewOrdersRow()
   order.Address = "Whatever" 'set properties of the order
   ds.Orders.Add(order) 'put the new row in the local datatable, not saved to db yet

   'put a product on an order
   ds.OrderItems.AddOrderItemsRow(prodToAdd, order, ...) 'directly add an orderitem row linking the Product and the Order

   'save to db
   tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(ds)
```

If you don't have a manager, you must insert the rows to the db in the right order yourself:

```vb
ordersTableAdapter.Update(ds.Orders) 'yes, the method is called update, but it runs an INSERT sql for rows in an Added rowstate

orderItemsTableAdater.Update(ds.OrderItems)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214867/discussion-on-answer-by-caius-jard-how-to-insert-customer-and-order-info-at-same).

Comment: @LachePorter Ahh, one of the things I've always disliked about comments moving to chat is that we don't get updates any more so it's a lot easier to lose the conversation. Yes, you might not have a server set up (at least thats what it looks like) but be assured that there is a SQL Server running on your machine, and probably the MDF db file is in your project but every time you run your project it is dynamically attached to the local sql server and used that way. It would probably be less confusing if you used SQL Server Managemnt Studio to ...

Comment: @LachePorter permanently attach the DB to the sql server and then change your connection string (it probably mentions DataDirectory) so that it targets localhost server and uses the attached DB